docker compose not working: (root) Additional property platform is not allowed
Running within portainer community edition 2.19.5 on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B.
Docker version 26.1.4, build 5650f9b.
Trying to get below docker compose stack for Duplicati to deploy:
---
version: '2.1'

platform: linux/armv7

services:
  duplicati:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/duplicati:latest
    container_name: duplicati
    environment:
      - PUID=0
      - PGID=0
      - TZ=Europe/London
    volumes:
      - /portainer/Configs/Duplicati:/config
      - /mnt/Backups-Duplicati:/backups
      - /portainer/Configs:/source
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
    restart: unless-stopped

The error message recieved:
failed to deploy a stack: validating /data/compose/43/docker-compose.yml: (root) Additional property platform is not allowed

I have tried using multiple different versions such as 3, 3.8, 2.4 and also without the version statement at all.
I initially didn't have the platform statement which results in the below error.
failed to deploy a stack: duplicati Pulling no matching manifest for linux/arm/v7 in the manifest list entries


Have you tried putting the platform statement indented under duplicati, I believe this is a syntax error.

If you're using a version of Compose that honors version:, also be aware that it was added in file format 2.4, and that it's not at all present in file format 3.x.  File format 2.1 won't support it.

You should put the platform keyword under your services (indented under duplicati), not at the root (unindented above services).
services:
  duplicati:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/duplicati:latest
    platform: linux/armv7
    container_name: duplicati
    environment:
      - PUID=0
      - PGID=0
      - TZ=Europe/London
    volumes:
      - /portainer/Configs/Duplicati:/config
      - /mnt/Backups-Duplicati:/backups
      - /portainer/Configs:/source
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
    restart: unless-stopped

